# Точка в имени JSON

Tags: json, node.js

Вот есть такая задача, есть JSOn документ, в котором есть строка Ф.И.О., как получить доступ к содержимому, например, `json_sheet[36].должность` выводит нормальное значение, а     `json_sheet[36].Ф\.И\.О\.` не получается, выводит такую     `(json_sheet[36].╨д.╨Ш.╨Ю.)` ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользоваться обращением к объекту, как к массиву (может быть, поможет):

```
   json_sheet[36]["Ф.И.О."]
```

UPD: ошибся с точкой, исправил.

**Обновление**

Вообще по хорошему, можно распечатать объект в консоли браузера и посмотреть, как он точно устроен. После этого уже использовать для обращения синтаксис массивов: `obj[prop][prop][prop]`. Выше комментарий исправил тоже, там ошибка в точке была между скобками.

Comment: не помогает, всёравно ошибка, сразу скажу что я попробовал что знаю и ничего невышло, к стати в строке *json_sheet[36].Ф.И.О.* точки экранированы обратным слэшом, но его не показывает форум

Comment: так заработало, спасибо, неподумал о том чтобы работать JSON как с простым многомерным массивом :)